# password stored in browser cache in plain text, and readable using RAM reading tools

Tags: security, web-applications, passwords

I have a simple web login POC application, and after givng the username and password on the login page, and clicking on "Login" button, POST action happens, and the userid and password are sent to the servlet for validation. 
Everything is fine sofar.
Now, when i read the RAM of the browser(iexplore) using tools like WinHex, the username and password i gave are visible in clear text, as below.

application/x-www-form-urlencoded    "username=myusername&userpass=myuserpwd"

I assume that this is the POST data packet, which the browser stores.

Can someone help to find a way to clear it, or prevent it from storing in RAM?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why's that question tagged with `java`?